# View.Invisible - images stay on the screen

Tags: android, xml, view, visibility

I trying to set visibility of my imageview , button and textview. But they still there when I run the program.
I tried the View.GONE but that just remove all the textview, imageview and button. But I just want to hide and then show.

```
               list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) 
                {
                                                if(baglanti.DegerDogruMu() == true)
                        {
                            ekvar = true; **// If true there is an attachment**
                            gelen = baglanti.EkinIsmi();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ekvar = false; **// False = no attachment**
                        }

                                }
```

**Then I put the result in the intent.**

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(ListeleActivity.this, GoruntuleActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(ekvarmı, ekvar);
startActivity(intent);
```

**And the other Activity
call this method for with adding the "ekvar"**

```
    public void ListOnClicklendiginde(final int position , ArrayList<String> bodyliste , ArrayList<String> kimdenlist , ArrayList<String> konulist, boolean ekvarmı  , ArrayList<String> ekinismi)
        {
**// First I hide the "attachment things"**


   dosyaAdi.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        atacResim.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ekButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

**// If there is an attachment then visible the things. (I debug for the no attachment email and it fall the false so the statement is working ok)**


    if( ekvarmı == true)
                {
                    dosyaAdi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    atacResim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ekButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                else
                {
                    dosyaAdi.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    atacResim.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ekButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                 }
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ekTablo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="8dp"
        android:layout_y="102dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewAttachment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_email_attachment" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dosyaAdi"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonEkIndir"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dosyaAdi"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_indir" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The red squares
At the picture they have to hide
[image: The red squares]

Comment: Where are you attempting to execute the code shown above?

Comment: At listview item onClick. Actually List Item OnClick call a method this code is into that method

Comment: This code looks good, View.Gone will completely remove the view. You have to use View.Visible and View.Invisible. Show some more code, how you are using onClick in listview.

Comment: I will edit my code under my question now, but first, Can @drawable/ic_indir and @drawable/ic_email_attachment stay on the screen? Maybe they stay on the screen I thougt.

Comment: I edit my code sample. I hope it is clear

Comment: Meanwhile, with this code when I click on no attachment mails attachment part is invisible like I want and when I click the mail with attachment the attachment part is coming and then I click the mail with no attachment the attachment part is still there. I think I should reset the variable somewhere

Comment: Looks like you are trying to change the visibility of Views when an item is pressed in the ListView. Are your "imageview , button and textview" part of a row in ListView?

Comment: No, I have a listview and when you click on the item. Then other activity is starting and the show screen is open. Imageview , button and textview are on this show screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to made your views **invisible in XML** and change your Java code like this

```
if( ekvarmı == true)
            {
                dosyaAdi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                atacResim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ekButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
```

Comment: I tried this seems like work, yes. But it didnt change anything. I am assuming , the source of problem is; when I click mail with no attachment ekvarmı=false; and then I click mail with attachment ekvarmı=true; and then I click mail with no attachment ekvarmı=true(it should be false) , but I think it is still true and the attachment part is still coming on screen when I click on no attachment mail. I have to reset the ekvarmı after the onclick but I tried this offcourse but it didnt work..

Comment: Use Logcat to print the value of variables and use Android Debugging System to track changes to your variables.

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved problem like I said ekvarmı was staying at  ekvarmı=true , I solved with Log and true debug. Thanks again.